# Javascript disable pause button from being clicked/pausing audio

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8LczkwLz/

HMTL:

```
<audio id="yourAudio" preload='none'>
    <source src='http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.m4a' type='audio/mpeg' />
</audio>
<a href="#" id="audioControl"><img src="http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/play1-150x150.png"></a>
```

JS:

```
var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'),
    ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

ctrl.onclick = function () {

    pause_html='<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/media-and-navigation-buttons-square/512/Button_4-128.png">';

    play_html='<img src="http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/play1-150x150.png">';

    // Update the Button
    var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === pause_html;
    ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? play_html : pause_html;

    // Update the Audio
    var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
    yourAudio[method]();

    // Prevent Default Action
    return false;
};



    document.getElementById('yourAudio').addEventListener('ended', function(){
  ctrl.innerHTML=play_html;

    });
```

Is there a way to disable the pause button from being clicked/pausing the audio? The audio files I will be playing last at most a few seconds so there isn't really a need to pause in the middle of them. That being said I want the pause button to display while the audio is playing just as a visual cue to the user.

Comment: Did you copy and paste this code from somewhere? Because if you didn't you should definitely be able to figure out where to put an "if" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I'd think you would always give the user the ability to pause something if they wish, just from a usability standpoint. However to answer your question, I would utilize [.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) and an if else statement.

```
//Check the whether you are playing audio
if(ctrl.innerHTML == play_html){
     // Update the Button
    var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === pause_html;
    ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? play_html : pause_html;

    // Update the Audio
    var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
    yourAudio[method]();

}else{
    ctrl.preventDefault();
}
```

This was tested and worked in your jsfiddle